# How can I make an offset when I use fixed position of header?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, dom

At the moment I am working on web-site. It has a fixed position of header. I wrote the script that allows me scroll to desired block, by clicking a button. At the moment I'm facing an issue, my header closes part of block. I have to make an offset that meet the header height, but I don't know how to do it.

```
   var butn = document.getElementById("btn");
    var dp = document.getElementById("skills");

    function scrollInSkills(){
        dp.scrollIntoView({
            behavior: "smooth",
            block: "start"
        })
    }
    butn.addEventListener("click", scrollInSkills)
```

Answer (score 0):

I deal with IT. I was a bad approach to use js for this purposes. It is a better way to use anchor for scroll. And After that we have to make padding on targeted block